# finding the difference in sql query

Tags: mysql

hi guys im new with SQL knowledge

im getting this error

```
SELECT `name`, `kills`, `deaths` 
FROM `pvp_ladder` 
ORDER BY (kills-deaths) DESC, `kills` DESC, `deaths` ASC
```

MySQL said: Documentation

```
> \#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 
'SELECT `name`, `kills`, `deaths` FROM `pvp_ladder` ORDER BY (kills-deaths) DESC,' at line 1
```

But when i do this i dont get any error at all

```
SELECT `name`, `kills`, `deaths` 
FROM `pvp_ladder` 
ORDER BY (kills/deaths) DESC, `kills` DESC, `deaths` ASC
```

Comment: Get rid of brackets in order by clause.

Comment: SELECT name, kills, deaths FROM pvp_ladder ORDER BY (kills/deaths) DESC, kills DESC, deaths ASC


but when i do this mate its working. thats a equation for KDA in our game, but we decided that instead of KILLS divided by DEATH

we want to make it KILLS minus DEATH but when i do that, it gives me error


i mean 

this >> (kills/deaths)  is working 
but this >> (kill-deaths)  not working

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue on my mariadb server or in mysql https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kXCiuzc7bLo7FcwjKqZ81T/0 nor would I expect this query to be an issue. Perhaps the error stems from something before the published code.?

Comment: what's the data type of kills and deaths? when I try with int, it's working

Comment: both are smallint

Comment: these are my columns, 

char_id int(11)                     UNSIGNED
name varchar(30) latin1_swedish_ci
account_id int(11)             UNSIGNED
kills smallint(4)                      UNSIGNED
deaths smallint(4)              UNSIGNED

Comment: just to clarify guys, when i do the division equation its working

but with sutraction its not

Comment: I know but don't accept there is problem with your published code

Comment: i cannot replicate this... https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=818b3ac5f870338309a0e8221c27123e

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using - in the column names, you can see more documentation in [Identifier Names](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/identifier-names/) so your query will be:

```
SELECT `name`, `kills`, `deaths` 
FROM `pvp_ladder` 
ORDER BY kills_deaths DESC, `kills` DESC, `deaths` ASC
```

In order to do this, you need to modify your column name in your database.